# Activate Autoplay based on allow="autoplay" attribute in iframe - Google Autoplay Policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, autoplay

I really tried to find an answer but couldn't. 
Google have changed their [Autoplay Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) .

I am loading an iframe with Src to independent code, like this:

```html
<iframe frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" allow="autoplay"
src="myurl" 
 width="640" height="480">
</iframe>
```

myurl is a path the a video player. 
I want to check if 'allow="autoplay"' was passed as iframe attribute where the player code is, and the decide if to set auto play or not.

Note, that the site where the iframe is loaded is a different site' with different code and it even sites on a different server then the myurl site.

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: So there is no other way to know if allow="autoplay" was set then to ask the other site programmer to post a massage?

It feels like a very complicated solution. Are you sure there is no other way? I don't want to change the attr, only to check it.

Comment: I am sure about interacting with the iframe, but just checking it, i am not sure,you can test it out !

Comment: Lol! If I knew how I wouldn't post this question. 
Maybe someone will know.

Comment: It actually depends on your url you want to load in the iframe, if you have control over it or not?

Comment: and yeah it's actually possible with something like : 
$("#iframe").contents().find("#content")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can not been done. 
You need to use a promises to check if the auto play succeeded.
I used [googles way of doing it](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

Hope it will saves some time to someone :)